# Android sending HTTP file parameters and non file via HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, http, post, httpurlconnection

i have this code for upload files via http:

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);
            URL url = new URL(SERVER_URL);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);//Allow Inputs
            connection.setDoOutput(true);//Allow Outputs
            connection.setUseCaches(false);//Don't use a cached Copy
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            connection.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file",selectedFilePath);



            //creating new dataoutputstream
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

            //writing bytes to data outputstream
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                    + selectedFilePath + "\"" + lineEnd);

            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
```

but i need to send user info too like mail /password

i tried this way but only file is uploaded and user info goes empty:

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);
            URL url = new URL(SERVER_URL);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);//Allow Inputs
            connection.setDoOutput(true);//Allow Outputs
            connection.setUseCaches(false);//Don't use a cached Copy
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            connection.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file",selectedFilePath);
            connection.setRequestProperty("user",user);
```

i added connection.setRequestProperty("user",user); but on serverside it comes empty

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
```

how i can send both files and user info in the same httpurlconnection?

Answer (score 0):

i solved putting this code:

```
 dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"myparameter\"" + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(myvalue);
```

where myparameter is the parameter and myvalue is the value of the parameter